# How to redirect admin weather he login ? laravel

Tags: laravel

The idea is I make multi auth ( users , admins ) and everything is fine, and I have the link of Dashboard this

> http://code.test/adminPanel/login

when I log in to the Dashboard it's will be like this

> http://code.test/adminPanel

The problem is when I log in to the Dashboard and visit the first link  ( http://code.test/adminPanel/login ) it does not redirect me ( http://code.test/adminPanel ) because I'm already logged in, so How can I make a redirect if the admin is auth?

Comment: There should be a middleware named RedirectIfAuthenticated. Have a look in there.

Comment: @user3532758 You mean to create a new middleware and check if auth or not ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, are you using Laravel's auth methods?

Comment: My version is 5.8

Comment: When you browse the middleware folder, do you see a file named `RedirectIfAuthenticated`?

Comment: Yeah I can see it now

Comment: You set your redirect there. Good luck!